# Load AngularJS using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am attempting to load AngularJS to a page using jQuery. The reason for that is that I have a site that was build using jQuery but I want to take advantage of some of the amazingness of AngularJS to a particular page. So I did this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQ){
    jQ.getScript( "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ){

        var app = angular.module('app',[]).controller('pageController', function($scope) {

            console.log('Hello');
            $scope.data = 'success!';
        });
    });
});
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<html>
..
<body>
...
<div ngApp="app">
    <div ngController="pageController">
       {{data}}
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

There are two problems.

1. If I use "ng-app" instead of "ngApp", AngularJS throws an error saying

> Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name
>   or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify
>   the dependencies as the second argument.

2. I can see **app** and **pageController** are both loaded correctly, but **{{data}}** in html is not rendered and **console.log('Hello');** didn't get executed as well.

Scratching my for hours now. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, `ngApp` isn't a property Angular recognizes.. And there's a guide to manual bootstrapping your app: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

Comment: how does jquery come here? I still don't understand why you just can't use them side by side

Comment: Why do you need to use JQuery to load AngularJS? You can just load AngularJS the same way you load JQuery, with a `<script src="...">`tag. Otherwise, I'm afraid AngularJS won't be bootstrapped automatically, and you would need to invoke angular.run(). Is there any particular reason to load it in this "creative" way?

Comment: But why? Usually when people are trying to do weird things, its because they really don't know what they are doing.  Just load angular with a script tag like any other js.

Comment: That's for your comments guys. I need to rethink my approach. It seems backwards. It's part of learning for those who wonder why I asked this question. We all experience confusion when learning something new. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, you just wouldn't declare the `ng-app` and instead bootstrap your app manually:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQ){
    jQ.getScript( "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ){

        angular.module('app',[]).controller('pageController', function($scope) {

            console.log('Hello');
            $scope.data = 'success!';
        });

        angular.element(document).ready(function() {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
        });
    });
});
```

It's also `ng-controller`, not `ngController`

```
<div>
    <div ng-controller="pageController">
       {{data}}
    </div>
</div>
```